# jQuery Rotate lags after a few uses

Tags: jquery, html, css, rotation

I've created a compass like feature on my site but it points to menu items. I'm using the jQuery rotate plugin.

However, when I first load the site the compass works flawlessly, but after a few turns it starts skipping rather than a smooth animation.

I clear the queue for the element once each transition is done as that seemed to smooth it a bit but it still skips. Anyone know what could cause this? It works fine again once I refresh the page.

Edit: Sorry, of course code would be helpful. http://sitetest.kdmdesign.net

Comment: I think we'll need to see your code.

Comment: Could you please post some code? Or a link to your site. There's not enough info

Comment: :-) everybody had the same idea

Comment: we think you should post some code

Comment: Post your code  we will solve it

Comment: Added link to site, the the code isn't commented but it's very close to the top of the page.

Comment: I just loaded your site on Chrome and it hung my PC for about 20 seconds, then worked fine after that.

Comment: No problems this end at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens a lot with any jQuery animation in which the animation triggers can fire a large number of times in short succession — using stop() is a good safety net but it's often still not enough.

I would 'throttle' the event to stop it firing unmanageably often. [Ben Alman wrote an excellent explanation of throttling](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) as a preface to his equally [excellent jQuery plugin](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce) for throttling and debouncing.

#### Oh — *and*...

A reason your code in particular would be slow is that the event handlers are re-attached (and never detached) every time the user hovers over the inner page wrapper. I tweaked that here:

http://jsbin.com/welcome/59800/edit

Comment: Thank you very much. I've had to change the mouseout to mouseleave due to the jQuery bug where hovering over child elements triggers mouseout.